# How can I change default options in NUnit Build Step on TeamCity

Tags: nunit, teamcity, nunit-3.0

When I use NUnit runner type, TeamCity invokes nunit3-console.exe with “–noresult” parameter (same in documentation https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Getting+Started+with+NUnit#GettingStartedwithNUnit-Case4.NUnitBuildStep,options).

How to remove default option “–noresult” to make savings the tests result in XML file?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible, please vote for the [request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-44986) and see the suggested workarounds. Also please describe your use case and the expected result in the issue comments.